# What is the correct way to stop receiving streaming updates from an RTKQ?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I tried to call an unsubscribe function:

```
unsubscribeFromThingIds(arg.tids);
```

after the `await cacheEntryRemoved;` line in [this example](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/streaming-updates#websocket-chat-api).

The function is defined like this:

```
export const unsubscribeFromThingIds = (tids: string[]) => {
  followedThingIds = followedThingIds.filter(
    id => !tids.includes(id)
  );
  const argument = { tids: followedThingIds } as ITimersChannelInitParams;
  myIo!.emit("configure timers channel", argument);
};
```

(where `myIo` is the Socket.IO client)

This is not working currently for me. I am currently debugging this issue.

I also tried to use an `useEffect` hook with a returned cleanup function for running it when the component unmounts, something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    unsubscribeFromThingIds(getTimersQueryParams.tids);
  };
}, [getTimersQueryParams]);
```

I want to ask for this information because I am not sure which one of the two ideas should I work on more, or if there is another thing I can do that is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you are just impatient? The cache entry will be removed 60 seconds (the `keepUnusedDataFor` option) after the last component stops using it.

Generally: using the endpoint lifecycle and awaiting `cacheEntryRemoved` is the right way to do this if you started the listener within `onCacheEntryAdded`. If you want it to happen earlier, just use a shorter `keepUnusedDataFor` duration.

Comment: I solved the issue as you said, by setting `keepUnusedDataFor` to `0`, since it is about highly dynamic data that should not get cached. Thank you!